# Getting a controller data in my layout view

Tags: grails, view, controller

I am working on grails and facing the problem that how can I get a controller's (in my case, contactGroup) data which is hasMany relations with the other (contact) controller in my layout view. Below is my domain class codes...

```
class Contact {
    String number
    String name

    ...

    static hasMany = [groups: ContactGroup, messages: Message]
    static belongsTo = [Message, ContactGroup]
}

class ContactGroup {
String groupName
String description

...

static hasMany = [contacts: Contact, messages: Message]
}
```

Below is my layout view code which is **meant to fetch all the groups with the number of contacts enclosed in parenthesis... Just like Gmail shows the contact and group list.**

```
 <h4>Contacts</h4>
    <g:link controller="contact" action="list" class="active"><h5>All (${smsserver.Contact?.list().size()})</h5></g:link>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <g:each in="${smsserver.ContactGroup}" var="c">
        <g:link controller="contact" action="list">${c.findAll()}<br></g:link>
    </g:each>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have got m:n relations. It means 1 contact has many groups and each group has many contacts. am I right? And you would like to show all groups and all contacts from group for given contact.
ok.

1. Get all groups for given contact:

   ${contact.groups} <%-- list of groups --%>

or more suitable

```
<ul>
<g:each in="${contact.groups}" var="group">
    <li>
        ${group.groupName} (${group.contacts.size()})
    </li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```

show all groups and contacts for given contact

```
<ul>
<g:each in="${contact.groups}" var="group">
    <li>
        <b>${group.groupName}</b> (${group.contacts.size()})
        <ul>
        <g:each in="${group.contacts}" var="c">
            <li>
                ${c.name}
            </li>
        </g:each>
        </ul>
    </li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```

Your controller:

```
class ContactController {

    def show(long id) {
        def contact = Contact.get(id)
        ['contact': contact]
        // or
        // render view:'YourPage', model:['contact': contact]
    }
}
```

for more details http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers

Comment: Did the same way... But it shows the error "Cannot get property 'groups' on null object"

Comment: you have to put the 'contact' to model.